# Custom validation for text field

Tags: angularjs

I have the requirement of having the following conditions in a single-line text field:

1. The first character should be an upper case letter.
2. The next two characters should be alphanumeric, but any letter should be in upper case.

Given the following code, how can I validate such conditions?

```
<input
    type="text"
    maxlength="3"
    ng-model="name"
    ng-change="name = name.toUpperCase();"
/>
```

Comment: If you've a new question, please make a new one; don't edit this one, it will invalidate the existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the correct pattern with the [`ngPattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) attribute.

You can't automatically convert a lower case letter typed by your user to upper case with [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), since the model is `undefined` if the input is invalid, but you can use the [`$parsers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) instead.

```
<input
    type="text"
    ng-model="name"
    ng-pattern="'[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}'"
/>
```

If you're using a version [between 1.3.0-beta.12 and 1.3.2](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/85eb9660ef67c24d5104a6a1921bedad0bd1b57e), use the pattern `^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}$` instead.

If you're using the version [1.3.0-beta.11 or lower](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/1be9bb9d3527e0758350c4f7417a4228d8571440), use the pattern `/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}$/` instead.

Comment: ng-pattern should be somewhat like this `ng-pattern="/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}$/"`

Comment: @pankajparkar I've added explanations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  ng-pattern to set your regular expression and

```
<input    type="text"    ng-model="name"
ng-pattern="'^[A-Z][A-Z\d]{2}'"
ng-change="name = name.toUppercase()" />
```

here you can test or create your regular expressions https://regex101.com/

Comment: How is that different from my answer?

Comment: I think we are on the same page.. i didnt see your answer postd sorry buddy